# How to filter a dataframe in Spark scala with relational operators as variables?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as below:

```
myDF:

+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|8    |
|8    |
|1    |
+-----+
```

The program reads from other computed dataframe and get the below two values:

```
val attr = 5
val opr = >
```

Now i need to filter `myDF` based on the values. So my result will be like below:

```
resultDF:
+-----+----------+
|value|result    |
+-----+----------+
|8    |GOOD      |
|8    |GOOD      |
|1    |BAD       |
+-----+----------+
```

Code I used:

```
val resultDF = myDF.withColumn("result", when(col("value") > attr, "GOOD").otherwise("BAD"))
```

Now, the attr and opr will change dynamically. Meaning the operator can be any of `>, <, >=, <=, <>` .

Based on the operator I receive my filter condition should change.
Like I need to use the variable for the operator.

Can someone please advise ?

```
val resultDF = myDF.withColumn("result", when(col("value") opr attr, "GOOD").otherwise("BAD"))
```

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL. There's lots of questions on SO about Spark and dynamic SQL.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you for the suggestion. I would like to do this on Spark data frame functions. Can you share some SO link where we can use similar to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as @[Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751573/andrew) said, it's bad idea to use dynamic sql without a big reason, because of undefined behavior, and difficulties in debugging.
Assume you have joined values with operators dataframe, then you can use this code:

```
import spark.implicits._

val appData: DataFrame = Seq(
  ("1", ">"),
  ("1", ">"),
  ("3", "<="),
  ("4", "<>"),
  ("6", ">="),
  ("6", "==")
).toDF("value", "operator")

val attr = 5

def compare(value: String, operator: String, sample: Int): String = {
  val isValueCorrectForAttr: Boolean = operator match {
    case ">" => value.toInt > sample
    case "<" => value.toInt < sample
    case ">=" => value.toInt >= sample
    case "<=" => value.toInt <= sample
    case "==" => value.toInt == sample
    case "<>" => value.toInt != sample
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Wrong operator: $operator")
  }
  if (isValueCorrectForAttr) "GOOD" else "BAD"
}

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dynamic_compare =  spark.udf.register("dynamic_compare", (v: String, op: String) => compare(v, op, attr))
appData.withColumn("result", dynamic_compare(col("value"), col("operator")))
```

if you don't have operator column, and just single operator, it can be more simple:

```
import spark.implicits._

val appData: DataFrame = Seq(
  "1",
  "1",
  "3",
  "4",
  "6",
  "6"
).toDF("value")

val attr = 5
val op = ">"

def compare(value: String, operator: String, sample: Int): String = {
  val isValueCorrectForAttr: Boolean = operator match {
    case ">" => value.toInt > sample
    case "<" => value.toInt < sample
    case ">=" => value.toInt >= sample
    case "<=" => value.toInt <= sample
    case "==" => value.toInt == sample
    case "<>" => value.toInt != sample
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Wrong operator: $operator")
  }
  if (isValueCorrectForAttr) "GOOD" else "BAD"
}

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val dynamic_compare =  spark.udf.register("dynamic_compare", (value: String) => compare(value, op, attr))
appData.withColumn("result", dynamic_compare(col("value")))
```

Comment: Thank you @Boris, I am testing this code snippet. However I am getting a "missing parameter type" error in  val dynamic_compare =  spark.udf.register("dynamic_compare", (v, op) => compare(v, op, attr))

Comment: @scalauser I updated value adding Sring type in lambda expression

Comment: It worked as expected. Thank you for the assistance.